# didnt understand a part of a code in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Can you please tell me how the 6th line of the following python code.

```
command = ""
started = False
while True:
    command = input("> ")
    if command == "start":
        if started:       #didnt understand this
            print("Car already started")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car started ... ready to go")
    elif command == "stop":
        print("Car stopped")
    elif command == "help":
        print('''start - to start the
                 stop - to stop the car
                 quit - to exit''')
    elif command == "quit":
        break
    else:
        print("I don't get it")
```

Comment: what did you not understand>

Answer (score 0):

The sixth line says that if started is `True` then `print("Car already started")`. it is simpler than saying `if started == True` but means the same thing as `started` evaluates to `True` or `False` only

Comment: But we have given the variable started the value False. So when we type if started: doesn't it mean if false.

Comment: yes it does but once you start the car and enter `start` command `started` would be equal to `False` and then the if statement would become `if true`